# SwiftUI How to center Text in a Form?

Tags: swiftui

`.multilineTextAlignment(.center)` seems to have no effect when the `Text` is inside `Form`, how can I center this item?

```
Form {
    Text("I am left aligned")
    Text("Why won't I center?").multilineTextAlignment(.center)
}
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This works.

```
Form {
    Text("I am left aligned")
    Text("I am centered!")
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
}
```

Comment: Try to remove every argument except the alignment-part.

Comment: removing all the other arguments does not create the wanted effect

Comment: @PaFi yeah removing other arguments doesn't work and it is kinda crazy behavior. Because the minimum and maximum values are zero and infinity anyways.

Comment: @PaFi You can get rid of all the dimensional arguments except `maxWidth`. You need that to cause the Text's block to fill the full width so that the centering isn't just happening on a block sitting on the left side of the screen.

Comment: Using `frame` only doesn't cause wrapped text to be centered on all lines. For that, [use both frame and multilineTextAlignment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67149982/145173).

Answer (score 16):

You can wrap your text into `HStack`:

```
Form {
    Text("I am left aligned")
    HStack {
        Spacer()
        Text("I am centered!")
        Spacer()
    }
}
```

Comment: Damn, I feel like I should have been able to figure that out myself.

Answer (score 15):

Use `frame` to expand the text's frame to the full width and `multilineTextAlignment` to cause text (including wrapped text) to be centered.

```swift
Form {
    Text("Centered text, even if wraps")
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
}
```

Comment: absolutely sure this is the best answer

Comment: While the accepted answer may work in some cases, it does not work in all instances.

Answer (score 4):

In case you need to center several items in the center of forms, here's a struct that accepts an object conforming to view for you to display:

```
struct CenterInForm<V: View>: View {

    var content: V

    init(_ content: V) { self.content = content }

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            content
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
CenterInForm(Text("TOTAL: $100"))
CenterInForm(Button("Confirm order") { print("placing order") })
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have two elements (i.e. 2 Texts) inside a HStack and need to put the second Text in the center, a little trick is to insert a third hidden element like the first one.

```
HStack(alignment: .center) {
            Button(action: {
                print("later...")
            }) {
                Text("Later")
            }
            .font(font)
            Text("Centered Text")
                .foregroundColor(SwiftUI.Color(.white))
                .frame(minWidth: 0,
                       maxWidth: .infinity,
                       minHeight: 0,
                       maxHeight: .infinity,
                       alignment: .center)
            Button(action: {
                print("later...")
            }) {
                Text("Later")
            }
            .hidden()
        }
```